# C# stop data download in web browser

Tags: c#, browser

I need a solution for visiting web page but not downloading data. I have a set of links to be visited, but all i need is server to register i have been in page! What would you suggest!

So far tryed

`if (webBrowser1.StatusText.Contains("remaining"))
            {
                webBrowser1.Stop();
            }`

but that doesn`t seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply stop it by controlling output of type application/octatestream

You can watch for this value in content-type header. If you are getting this value, it is for sure not a web page.

In addition to this, you can also block application/pdf, application/xxx headers so as other files can also be selectively blocked.

There are several combinations that you can try.